# Selecting MySQL views using $wpdb class

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I am building a Wordpress site and it is connected to a MySQL database. I am using the wordpress class *wpdb* (https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) to interact with the database. With that class, I am able to query TABLES of my database, but not Views.

I need to be able to select Views of my database. Is this something that is not allowed with *wpdb*, or is my code just wrong? Is there a way to query views the same way I can query tables using wpdb?

I have tried using the query function, as well as treating a view the same way I treat a table, but it does not work. It returns empty.

Query method:

```
$test = $mydb->query( 
$mydb->prepare( 
"
         SELECT name FROM $mydb->$view_name
 WHERE id = 1"
 )
);

echo $test; //returns empty; should return a name
```

Table method:

```
$test = $mydb->get_var(
"select name from $view_name WHERE id = 1"
);

echo $test; //returns empty; should return a name
```

Any suggestions? Am I able to connect to my database using something other than $wpdb (does Wordpress allow that?).

Comment: ```name``` seems to be a reserved word in MySQL ([reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html)). Try surrounding it with back-ticks (`) like this. You should be seeing some errors, do you keep an eye on the logs? Also, when you have doubts in your queries, you can simply copy the raw query and execute it into phpMyAdmin or whatever tool you are using to access your database manually.

Comment: Ah! You fixed my problem! You're probably right about the "name" being reserved, but another problem I found was that my view was named something that caused an error! I tried selecting my view in phpMyAdmin and that was the (first) problem. 

(For posterity, my view was called "broccoli-and-roots-1price", and that caused an error). 

Thank-you!

Comment: @Avalanche You solved my problem, so I can award you the Accepted Answer if you post an answer, if you want!

Comment: Well, thanks, very kind of you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`name` seems to be a reserved word in MySQL ([reference](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/keywords.html)). Try surrounding it with back-ticks (`) like this:

```
SELECT `name` FROM ...
```

You should be seeing some errors, do you keep an eye on the logs? Also, when you have doubts in your queries, you can simply copy the raw query and execute it into phpMyAdmin or whatever tool you are using to access your database manually

Comment: back-ticks, of course! I need to remember to use back-ticks to avoid future errors!